# Android send success but php can not receive anything

Tags: java, php, android, http, post

When I do this in Android

```
client.post("http://10.0.2.2/cubsfit/cubsfit_sync/insertuser.php", params, new AsyncHttpResponseHandler() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(String response) {


                Log.d(TAG, "Success" + response);
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(int statusCode, Throwable error, String content) {

            }
        });
```

I got the log

```
D/ContentValues: SuccesssleepJSON=%5B%7B%22wakeuptime%22%3A%222018-02-23+10%3A30%22%2C%22sleeptime%22%3A%222018-02-23+10%3A25%22%2C%22id%22%3A%221%22%2C%22babyid%22%3A%22100%22%7D%2C%7B%22wakeuptime%22%3A%222018-02-23+12%3A35%22%2C%22sleeptime%22%3A%222018-02-23+12%3A30%22%2C%22id%22%3A%222%22%2C%22babyid%22%3A%22100%22%7D%5D<br />
             <font size='1'><table class='xdebug-error xe-notice' dir='ltr' border='1' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='1'>
             <tr><th align='left' bgcolor='#f57900' colspan="5"><span style='background-color: #cc0000; color: #fce94f; font-size: x-large;'>( ! )</span> Notice: Undefined index: HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA in D:\wamp64\www\cubsfit\cubsfit_sync\insertuser.php on line <i>5</i></th></tr>
             <tr><th align='left' bgcolor='#e9b96e' colspan='5'>Call Stack</th></tr>
             <tr><th align='center' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>#</th><th align='left' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>Time</th><th align='left' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>Memory</th><th align='left' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>Function</th><th align='left' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>Location</th></tr>
             <tr><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='center'>1</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='center'>0.0003</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='right'>246392</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec'>{main}(  )</td><td title='D:\wamp64\www\cubsfit\cubsfit_sync\insertuser.php' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>...\insertuser.php<b>:</b>0</td></tr>
             </table></font>
             []
```

At php side, when I do

```
$raw_post = file_get_contents('php://input');
print_r($raw_post);
print_r($GLOBALS["HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA"]);
```

I got just

```
<br />
<font size='1'><table class='xdebug-error xe-notice' dir='ltr' border='1' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='1'>
<tr><th align='left' bgcolor='#f57900' colspan="5"><span style='background-color: #cc0000; color: #fce94f; font-size: x-large;'>( ! )</span> Notice: Undefined index: HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA in D:\wamp64\www\cubsfit\cubsfit_sync\insertuser.php on line <i>5</i></th></tr>
<tr><th align='left' bgcolor='#e9b96e' colspan='5'>Call Stack</th></tr>
<tr><th align='center' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>#</th><th align='left' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>Time</th><th align='left' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>Memory</th><th align='left' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>Function</th><th align='left' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>Location</th></tr>
<tr><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='center'>1</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='center'>0.0003</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='right'>244376</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec'>{main}(  )</td><td title='D:\wamp64\www\cubsfit\cubsfit_sync\insertuser.php' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>...\insertuser.php<b>:</b>0</td></tr>
</table></font>
```

The question is why I can not get this in my PHP

```
sleepJSON=%5B%7B%22wakeuptime%22%3A%222018-02-23+10%3A30%22%2C%22sleeptime%22%3A%222018-02-23+10%3A25%22%2C%22id%22%3A%221%22%2C%22babyid%22%3A%22100%22%7D%2C%7B%22wakeuptime%22%3A%222018-02-23+12%3A35%22%2C%22sleeptime%22%3A%222018-02-23+12%3A30%22%2C%22id%22%3A%222%22%2C%22babyid%22%3A%22100%22%7D%5D
```

Comment: As the error specifies, HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA is undefine. Maybe try some simple HttpRequest first to check if mobile and php server side are connected.

Comment: @meowok, if mobile and php are connected,  there should be something shown when I do `print_r`? how can I see what does they transfer?